# Formula For Finding the Next Near Consecutive Perfect Square

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, terminology

For any three consecutive members of a sequence, the first and third members are near consecutive.

1 squared is 1. 2 squared is 4. So 1 and 4 are consecutive perfect squares.

1 squared is 1. 3 squared is 9. So 1 and 9 are near consecutive perfect squares.

I want to verify this formula to go from any perfect square to the next near consecutive perfect square. Let a be any perfect square. Let c be the next near consecutive perfect square. Here is the formula:

a+4(1+$\sqrt a$)=c

Example:

49+4(1+$\sqrt 49$)=81

Did I get the formula right? Is my terminology ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! Its right!
If your square is $a$ then the number that originate it is $\sqrt{a}$ thus the next near consecutive perfect square is $(\sqrt{a}+2)^2$, but $(\sqrt{a}+2)^2 = a + 4(\sqrt{a}+1)$

Answer (score 1):

Actually the next near perfect square would be $64$. A better formula $a + 2(a)^{\frac12}+1 = c$

Example being:

$$49 + 2(49)^{\frac12} + 1 = 64$$
$$49 + 2(7) + 1 = 64$$
$$49 + 14 + 1 = 64$$
$$64=64$$

Answer (score -1):

I have found there is a easier way to do this

(N+1)squared
And
(N-1)squared

Like for example
(1+1)squared is 4 then (4-1)squared is 9 then (9-1)squared is 18

Comment: I just figured out this is incorrect.